# How to wait for iframe contents to load using Selenium WebDriver or JS?

Tags: java, iframe, webdriver, load, wait

I'm trying to wait for the contents of an iFrame to load but I'm unable to do so without using Thread.sleep().

Do you guys have an idea on how to do this?

Here's my Java code:

```
   driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("iframe.f-iframe")));
//Thread.sleep(3000);

    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.cssSelector("iframe.f-iframe")));

    String source = driver.getPageSource();
    System.out.println(source); //prints an empty iframe at this point

    waitForElementVisibility(driver, link, 5); //waits using fluent wait for the element
    link.click();
    driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

If I uncomment the Thread.sleep() and comment out all of the waits it works fine.

Web page code:

```
<html><body><iframe class="f-iframe x-item"><html><body>...</body></html></iframe</body></html>
```

Comment: What error are you getting when you take out the `Thread.Sleep`?

Comment: If I remember correctly I was getting a TimeoutException or NoSuchElementException. It's like the link isn't there although if I add breakpoints (before the line where I get the exception) the link is displayed.

Comment: Try moving the `frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt` and the `WebDriverWait ` above the `driver.switchTo().frame` to start. Based on the docs, that method is to wait for the frame to be available to switch to. https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/M_OpenQA_Selenium_Support_UI_ExpectedConditions_FrameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt.htm

Comment: Can you also post the locator that you are using to get your link?

Comment: @MichielBugher Yes, you are right it should be before that line, I think I tried it that way and just moved it down since it didn't work, should have removed it since it's not relevant anymore. I tried it again now as you suggested but it can't find the iframe using the CSS locator for it or index 0. The locator I'm using for the link is a simple XPATH search by link text: //a[contains(text(),'Link Text')]. The locators are not the issue as they do work fine when using Thread.sleep()

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this code and see if it works for you?

```
string iFrameLocator = "iframe.f-iframe"
string linkLocator = "//a[contains(text(),'Link Text')]"

driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(iFrameLocator)));

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(linkLocator)));

String source = driver.getPageSource();
System.out.println(source);

WebElement link = driver.findElement(By.xpath(linkLocator))
link.click();

driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

Comment: It fails with: org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for visibility of element located by By.xpath: //a[contains(text(),'Link Text')] (tried for 5 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval)

Comment: I forgot to mention that it fails like that even though the link is present and the locator is correct. I also used debug mode and put a breakpoint on the "WebDriverWait wait =..." line to make sure everything is good. It's something with the frame but not sure what else I can do.